# Unable to send a file using MultipartFile in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, multipartform-data

Actually my question is same with this question: [How to upload images and file to a server in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125191/how-to-upload-images-and-file-to-a-server-in-flutter), I have tried the solution there but I when I try to check the backend, the file is still null
Here is the part of the code

```
var url = Uri.parse("$loginUrl/saving");
      var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
      request.headers.addAll(headers);
      request.fields['start_date'] =
          "2021-10-10 14:42:09.369599"; //"$startDate";
      request.fields['end_date'] = "2021-10-10 14:41:09.369599"; // "$endDate";
      request.fields['id_download'] = "0";
File file = File(
          "/data/user/0/com.example.project/cache/file_picker/ic_launcher.png");
      Uint8List bytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
      List<int> sending = bytes;

      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          'file_upload', file.readAsBytesSync(),
          // contentType: new MediaType('application', 'octet-stream'),
          filename: "ic_launcher.png"));
      print(request);
      print("kkkk");
      var res = await request.send().timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
      final respStr = await res.stream.bytesToString();
```

is there something that I should add more?

Comment: pass `bytes` to `fromBytes()` method, now you call `file.readAsBytesSync()` twice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927993/how-to-return-the-data-in-multipartrequest-in-flutter

Comment: @pskink I don't know what you mean would you like to give an example?

Comment: @pskink I have tried this: ```request.files.add(
        await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          'file_upload', bytes,
          // contentType: new MediaType('application', 'x-tar'),
          filename: "ic_launcher.png"));``` but still get the same result

Comment: @ShahryarRafique I have tried it also and I still get null in backend

Comment: Have you tried it in the postman? If available send me the link of postman collection. I will try to resolve it.

Comment: and are you sure that `bytes` contains valid data? what if you `print(bytes.length)`?

Comment: @pskink yeah I have printed it, and the length is 5970

Comment: @ShahryarRafique I have tried it in postman, and it is success but when I try it using flutter, always getting null

Comment: @uyhaW did you try the link i sent you previously.

Comment: @ShahryarRafique yes I have tried it

Comment: have you resolved this I am facing this issue

Comment: why not try `MultipartFile.fromPath` instead of `.fromBytes` since you have the filepath of the image anyway?

Comment: I think the problem may be in the part of `http.MultipartFile.fromBytes`. I just met the similiar issue and fixed it by using `dio.MultipartFile.fromBytes` from [dio package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)